# Xpages - Remove selected items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpages

Does anyone know how to remove selected items from an array?

```
var view:NotesView = getComponent("viewPanel2");
var UtbildningarArray = new Array();
viewScope.col = view.getSelectedIds();
if (viewScope.col.length > 0){
for (i=0; i<viewScope.col.length; i++){
    var docid = viewScope.col[i];
        if (docid != null) {
            var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docid);
            UtbildningarArray.push(doc.getItemValueString("Namn"))
        }
    }
}
document1.removeItemValue("Utbildningar",UtbildningarArray);
document1.save();
```

I have tried, removeEntry and splice but I don't get it work.

Thanks,
Jonas

Edit:

You are right, have added this in the code:

```
var view:NotesView = getComponent("viewPanel2");
var UtbildningarArray = new Array();
var UtbildningarArray = new Array();
var FieldUtbArray = new Array(getComponent('inputHidden1').getValue());

viewScope.col = view.getSelectedIds();
if (viewScope.col.length > 0){
    for (i=0; i<viewScope.col.length; i++){
        var docid = viewScope.col[i];
            if (docid != null) {
                var doc = database.getDocumentByID(docid);
                UtbildningarArray.push(doc.getItemValueString("Namn"))
            }
        }
    }

document1.replaceItemValue("Utbildningar",FieldUtbArray.slice(UtbildningarArray));
document1.save();
```

I'm saving what the user selected in a hidden input, and when the user clicks the "Remove programs" button I display the selected courses in the view. Then should the user be able to click a checkbox and remove the selected course(s). Now when I save nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it work!

```
for (var i = 0; i < FieldUtbArray.length; i++) {
    found = false;
    // find a[i] in b
    for (var j = 0; j < UtbildningarArray.length; j++) {
        if (FieldUtbArray[i] == UtbildningarArray[j]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        result.push(FieldUtbArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to show more what you want to remove.

Below you have to code snippets that will remove an entry from an js array.

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=remove-an-entry-from-an-array-of-strings

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.se/2010/10/code-snippet-arraysplice-according-to.html

Comment: I changed my post now.

Comment: If you look at the spec for slice http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp I don't think you can remove one JS Array from another. you need to loop thru them and creating a new array

Comment: Thanks Fredik, I'll have to check further on that.

Comment: +1 for Tommy Valand's article. It's amazing that Array.prototype.splice() doesn't works in Domino 8.5.3. ¿Do you know if it works in Domino 9?